# Try to use paypal invocing app in my website but following are error found

Tags: php, paypal, invoices

I have try most of the class that are availble on internet but when i execute some error found here 
            ---------------------------------Send Invoice API-------------------------------------

```
Failure
Invalid request parameter: quantity must be in the range 0.001 through 9999.999 → quantity = 0
```

but i have set this quantity =1 then why it given this error... i have use following code of

```
require_once('class.invoice.php');

                    $ppInv = new PaypalInvoiceAPI("sandbox");       //pass 'live' for actual paypal account

                    /**
                     * Populate Data
                     */
                    $aryData['language'] = "en_US";
                    $aryData['merchantEmail'] = $business;

                    $aryData['payerEmail'] = "eyemedianetwork@gmail.com";
                    $aryData['currencyCode'] = "USD";
                    //$aryData['orderId'] = "0001";
                    $aryData['orderId'] = strtotime('now');
                    $aryData['invoiceDate'] = "2014-09-19T05:38:48Z";
                    $aryData['dueDate'] = "2014-12-31T05:38:48Z";
                    $aryData['paymentTerms'] = "Net45";   //[DueOnReceipt, DueOnDateSpecified, Net10, Net15, Net30, Net45]
                    $aryData['discountPercent'] = "0";
                    $aryData['discountAmount'] = "0";
                    $aryData['invoiceTerms'] = "These are Inovice Terms and Conditions";
                    $aryData['invoiceNote'] = "These are Invoice notes";
                    $aryData['merchantMemo'] = "This is Merchant Memo";
                    $aryData['shippingAmount'] = "10.00";
                    $aryData['shippingTaxName'] = "S Tax Name";
                    $aryData['shippingTaxRate'] = "5.00";
                    $aryData['logoURL'] = "https://xyx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/logo1.png";

                    $aryData['merchantFirstName'] = "Ashish";
                    $aryData['merchantLastName'] = "Sharma";
                    $aryData['merchantBusinessName'] = "Selling";
                    $aryData['merchantPhone'] = "";
                    $aryData['merchantFax'] = "";
                    $aryData['merchantWebsite'] = "";
                    $aryData['merchantCustomValue'] = "";

                    $aryData['merchantLine1'] = "Bhopal";
                    $aryData['merchantLine2'] = "Merchant Address Line 2";
                    $aryData['merchantCity'] = "Merchant City";
                    $aryData['merchantState'] = "Merchant State";
                    $aryData['merchantPostalCode'] = "462021";
                    $aryData['merchantCountryCode'] = "IN";

                    $aryData['billingFirstName'] = "Sam";
                    $aryData['billingLastName'] = "Peter";
                    $aryData['billingBusinessName'] = "Shiping";
                    $aryData['billingPhone'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingFax'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingWebsite'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingCustomValue'] = "";

                    $aryData['billingLine1'] = "Bhopal";
                    $aryData['billingLine2'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingCity'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingState'] = "";
                    $aryData['billingPostalCode'] = "462021";
                    $aryData['billingCountryCode'] = "IN";

                  $aryData['shippingFirstName'] = "Ashish";
                    $aryData['shippingLastName'] = "Sharma";
                    $aryData['shippingBusinessName'] = "Shipping Business Name";
                    $aryData['shippingPhone'] = "Shipping Phone";
                    $aryData['shippingFax'] = "Shipping Fax";
                    $aryData['shippingWebsite'] = "Shipping Website";
                    $aryData['shippingCustomValue'] = "Shipping Custom Value";

                    $aryData['shippingLine1'] = "India";
                    $aryData['shippingLine2'] = "Shipping Line 2";
                    $aryData['shippingCity'] = "Shipping City";
                    $aryData['shippingState'] = "Shipping State";
                    $aryData['shippingPostalCode'] = "Shipping Postal Code";
                    $aryData['shippingCountryCode'] = "US";

                    $aryItems[0]['name'] = "Individual Product";
                    $aryItems[0]['description'] = "Item 1 Description";
                    $aryItems[0]['date'] = "2014-09-20T05:38:48Z";
                    $aryItems[0]['quantity'] = "003";
                    $aryItems[0]['unitprice'] = "1";
                    $aryItems[0]['taxName'] = "";
                    $aryItems[0]['taxRate'] = "";

                    /**
                     * Create Invoice Task
                     */
                    echo "<br /><br />---------------------------------Send Invoice API-------------------------------------<br /><br />";
                    $res = $ppInv->doCreateInvoice($aryData, $aryItems);

                //    echo "<pre>";
                //    print_r($res);
                //    echo "</pre>";

                    if($res['responseEnvelope.ack']== "Success")
                    {
                        echo "<br />Success Creating Invoice: '{$res['invoiceID']}'";

                        echo "<br /><br />---------------------------------Send Invoice API-------------------------------------<br /><br />";

                        $res_send = $ppInv->doSendInvoice($res['invoiceID']);

                    //    echo "<pre>";
                    //    print_r($res_send);
                    //    echo "</pre>";

                        if($res_send['responseEnvelope.ack']== "Success")
                        {
                            echo "<br />Success Sending Invoice";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Get Error String
                            echo $ppInv->formatErrorMessages($res_send);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Get Error String
                        echo $ppInv->formatErrorMessages($res);
                    }


                ?>
```

This is the fuction

```
function prepareCreateInvoice($aryData, $aryItems)
                        {
                            $aryCreateInvoice = array();

                            if(trim(@$aryData['language'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['requestEnvelope.errorLanguage']  = $aryData['language'];   //en_US        //TODO
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantEmail'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantEmail']          = $aryData['merchantEmail'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['payerEmail'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.payerEmail']             = $aryData['payerEmail'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['currencyCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.currencyCode']           = $aryData['currencyCode'];   //USD TODO
                            if(trim(@$aryData['orderId'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.number']                 = $aryData['orderId'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['invoiceID'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoiceID']                 = $aryData['invoiceID'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['paymentTerms'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.paymentTerms']           = $aryData['paymentTerms'];   //[DueOnReceipt, DueOnDateSpecified, Net10, Net15, Net30, Net45]
                            if(trim(@$aryData['discountPercent'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.discountPercent']        = $aryData['discountPercent'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['discountAmount'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.discountAmount']         = $aryData['discountAmount'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['invoiceTerms'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.terms']                  = $aryData['invoiceTerms'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['invoiceNote'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.note']                   = $aryData['invoiceNote'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantMemo'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantMemo']           = $aryData['merchantMemo'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingAmount'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingAmount']         = $aryData['shippingAmount'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingTaxName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingTaxName']        = $aryData['shippingTaxName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingTaxRate'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingTaxRate']        = $aryData['shippingTaxRate'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['logoURL'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.logoUrl']                = $aryData['logoURL'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantFirstName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.firstName']     = $aryData['merchantFirstName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantLastName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.lastName']      = $aryData['merchantLastName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantBusinessName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.businessName']  = $aryData['merchantBusinessName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantPhone'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.phone']         = $aryData['merchantPhone'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantFax'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.fax']           = $aryData['merchantFax'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantWebsite'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.website']       = $aryData['merchantWebsite'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantCustomValue'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.customValue']   = $aryData['merchantCustomValue'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantLine1'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.line1']         = $aryData['merchantLine1'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantLine2'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.line2']         = $aryData['merchantLine2'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantCity'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.city']          = $aryData['merchantCity'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantState'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.state']         = $aryData['merchantState'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantPostalCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.postalCode']    = $aryData['merchantPostalCode'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['merchantCountryCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.merchantInfo.address.countryCode']   = $aryData['merchantCountryCode'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingFirstName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.firstName']      = $aryData['billingFirstName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingLastName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.lastName']       = $aryData['billingLastName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingBusinessName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.businessName']   = $aryData['billingBusinessName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingPhone'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.phone']          = $aryData['billingPhone'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingFax'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.fax']            = $aryData['billingFax'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingWebsite'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.website']        = $aryData['billingWebsite'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingCustomValue'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.customValue']    = $aryData['billingCustomValue'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingLine1'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.line1']          = $aryData['billingLine1'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingLine2'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.line2']          = $aryData['billingLine2'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingCity'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.city']           = $aryData['billingCity'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingState'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.state']          = $aryData['billingState'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingPostalCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.postalCode']     = $aryData['billingPostalCode'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['billingCountryCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.billingInfo.address.countryCode']    = $aryData['billingCountryCode'];

                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingFirstName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.firstName']     = $aryData['shippingFirstName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingLastName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.lastName']      = $aryData['shippingLastName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingBusinessName'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.businessName']  = $aryData['shippingBusinessName'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingPhone'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.phone']         = $aryData['shippingPhone'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingFax'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.fax']           = $aryData['shippingFax'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingWebsite'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.website']       = $aryData['shippingWebsite'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingCustomValue'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.customValue']   = $aryData['shippingCustomValue'];


                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingLine1'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.line1']         = $aryData['shippingLine1'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingLine2'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.line2']         = $aryData['shippingLine2'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingCity'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.city']          = $aryData['shippingCity'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingState'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.state']         = $aryData['shippingState'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingPostalCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.postalCode']    = $aryData['shippingPostalCode'];
                            if(trim(@$aryData['shippingCountryCode'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.shippingInfo.address.countryCode']   = $aryData['shippingCountryCode'];        //US TODO


                            $nLoop = count($aryItems);
                            for($cnt=0;$cnt<$nLoop;$cnt++)
                            {
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['name'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).name"]       = $this->adjustStringLength($aryItems[$cnt]['item_name']);
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['description'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).description"]= $this->adjustStringLength($aryItems[$cnt]['item_description']);
                                #if(trim(@$aryData['$aryItems[$cnt]['date']'])!= "")
                                    #$aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).date"]       = $aryItems[$cnt]['date'];
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['quantity'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).quantity"]   = $this->adjustStringLength($aryItems[$cnt]['item_quantity']);
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['unitprice'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).unitPrice"]  = $this->adjustStringLength($aryItems[$cnt]['item_unitprice']);
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['taxName'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).taxName"]    = $aryItems[$cnt]['taxName'];
                                if(trim(@$aryItems[$cnt]['taxRate'])!= "")
                                    $aryCreateInvoice["invoice.itemList.item($cnt).taxRate"]    = $aryItems[$cnt]['taxRate'];
                            }

                            if(trim(@$aryData['invoiceDate'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.invoiceDate']            = urldecode($aryData['invoiceDate']);     //2011-12-31T05:38:48Z
                            if(trim(@$aryData['dueDate'])!= "")
                                $aryCreateInvoice['invoice.dueDate']                = urldecode($aryData['dueDate']);

                //            $reqstr .= "&invoice.invoiceDate={$aryData['invoiceDate']}";
                //            $reqstr .= "&invoice.dueDate={$aryData['dueDate']}";

                            $request_string = http_build_query( $aryCreateInvoice );


                            return $request_string;
                        }#end of prepareCreateInvoice()
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete response from the PayPal which correlation id ?

Comment: Need to see the actual request getting generated from this.

Comment: Eshan add the function

Comment: I'm looking at your code and I see:  $aryItems[0]['quantity'] = "003";

Comment: Thanks Len_D i have this to 1,2,3 as on but its not working